# Intercambiar valores de un vector de direcciones

Tags: c++

Resulta que tengo un vector de direcciones de los valores de otro vector. me piden que organice luego el vector de direcciones en base a ordenar ascendentemente el los valores del vector de números pero sin modificarlo.

Por ejemplo, tengo el vector `numeros[5]={2,5,3,1,3}`, el vector `*direcciones[5]` seria igual a las direcciones de los valores del vector `numeros`, lo cuál ya pude hacer. Ahora necesito hacer que los valores del vector `*direccion` se intercambien de la forma, el menor numero del vector `numeros` es 1 entonces esa dirección debe quedar en la primera posición del vector de direcciones, luego viene el numero 2, entonces ahora la direccion de 2 debe quedar en la segunda posición del vector de direcciones y así sucesivamente pero sin modificar el vector de números.

Intenté hacer un ordenamiento de burbuja pero tomando el vector direcciones con doble apuntador porque con 1 muestra el contenido el cual son las direcciones, y con los dos asteriscos, muestra los valores que están en esas direcciones los cuales son básicamente los valores de números. Entonces intenté este ciclo:

```
int aux;
    for (int i=0; i<10-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<10; j++)
        {
            if(**(direcciones+i)>**(direcciones+j))
            {
                aux=**(direcciones+i) ;
                **(direcciones+i)=**(direcciones+j);
                **(direcciones+j)= aux;
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero esto al imprimir el vector direcciones de la forma `*(direcciones+i)` dentro de su respectivo `for`, no hizo ningún cambio, pero si pongo `**(direcciones+i)` ahí si me muestra los valores organizados de menor a mayor pero no se entonces porque no se cambian las direcciones. Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1):

No se si estás entendiendo cómo funcionan los punteros. Simplificando, un puntero es una variable que apunta a otra. Así pues, la memoria de tu programa se parecería a este ascii art:

```
                +---+---+---+---+---+
                | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
                |---|---|---|---|---|
direcciones --> | a | b | c | d | e |
                |-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|
                  |   |   |   |   |
                  v   v   v   v   v
                +---+---+---+---+---+
                | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
                |---|---|---|---|---|
numeros ------> | 2 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
                +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Como puedes ver, `direcciones` no contiene valores si no direcciones de memoria a elementos de `numeros`. Hasta ahí todo claro, el problema surge cuando des-referencias punteros.

Una variable declarada con un asterisco junto al **tipo** es un puntero a ese tipo: `int *a;` es un puntero (`*`) a entero (`int`). Cuando a una **variable** de tipo puntero se le anexa un asterisco, le estamos pidiendo el contenido de aquello a lo que apunta: `*a;` es dame el contenido de (`*`) ese puntero (`a`).

Por otro lado, las formaciones<sup>1</sup> pueden ser (y habitualmente son) interpretadas como un puntero al primer elemento. De manera que si tienes una formación de enteros como `int *direcciones[5]`, el **tipo** del primer elemento será `int **direcciones`, es decir puntero (`*`) a puntero (`*`) a entero (`int`), mientras que des-referenciar dos veces esa **variable** da como resultado el contenido del contenido de lo apuntado.

En conclusión, cuando haces esto

```
aux=**(direcciones+i);
**(direcciones+i)=**(direcciones+j);
**(direcciones+j)= aux;
```

No estás intercambiando las direcciones, estás intercambiando el **contenido del contenido** de aquello a lo que apuntan, ya que `**(direcciones+i)` se interpreta como: dame el contenido de (`*`) el contenido de (`*`) ese puntero (`direcciones`) desplazado unas posiciones (`+i`).

Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
constexpr int tamanyo = 5;
int numeros[tamanyo] {2, 5, 3, 1, 3};
int *direcciones[tamanyo] {numeros, numeros + 1, numeros + 2, numeros + 3, numeros + 4};

for (int i = 0; i != tamanyo; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j != tamanyo; ++j)
    {
        if (**(direcciones + i) > **(direcciones + j))
//          ^^                    ^^ <--- Comparar contenido de contenido
        {
            int *aux = *(direcciones + i);
//              ^      ^ <--- Intercambiar contenido
            *(direcciones + i) = *(direcciones + j);
//          ^                    ^ <--- Intercambiar contenido
            *(direcciones + j) = aux;
//          ^ <--- Intercambiar contenido
        }
    }
}
```

Por cierto, es mucho más sencillo de leer si usas el operador de indizado (`[]`) en lugar de aritmética de punteros:

```
for (int i = 0; i != tamanyo; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j != tamanyo; ++j)
    {
        if (*direcciones[i] > *direcciones[j])
        {
            int *aux = direcciones[i];
            direcciones[i] = direcciones[j];
            direcciones[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zZDPUoMwEMbPyVOs9VBacEZbeym0T@AbKIdMSJ1lIGFCcOp0eHbcUGqhevDoIX9297dfvqysqod3KbvuHrUsmkxBgqZ2VolyzzlqB6VAHSz4iTNpdO3UsbLg806UQn8a2MEm5sxndFMqa@rXoZLCaRXBJoJ1BE@0twO2zNAqKdFoNWaH7ugiA6HvugarcbAeB8@kzNnBWAi8PpKlx5iOu93FZAxhiAvOWO2y7VaaxkGSwOxFwLcXmPnU2BqmPQT0bYdKK1AFfIiCnunR5U92/qbnf7VC87xyOXHoPxzTdcrm3raHGR4guH10P7WRp54@4@dZi@ZI2tOuuC/fKE2h/Bco9xDp9ZWW96v9X4O3yjVWkwnedt0X)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación!! Apenas estoy empezando con esto. Y si se que usar aritmética de punteros en más complicado pero me piden que la use.